# Different overloaded operator in derived class from base class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I overload `operator*(float s)` in a Base class (and I do not make it virtual) and then in a Derived class I overload `operator*(mat4 m)` can I reasonably expect that the Derived class will then respond to both operator overloads?

I assume that an operator overload is like any other function: if it is not virtual and not overridden, then the Derived class has access to it in addition to any other overloads of that function/operator that are unique to the Derived class.

Of course, if it is not virtual but the Derived class also defined `operator*(float s)` then it would effectively be called only if the Derived was accessed via a `Derived*` pointer, otherwise, the base class version would be called even on the Derived class, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that an operator overload is like any other function: if it is not virtual and not overridden, then the Derived class has access to it in addition to any other overloads of that function/operator that are unique to the Derived class.

Just as with normal member functions, the [overload in the derived class hides the original](http://ideone.com/LUli8K), unless you [use `using`](http://ideone.com/jVmQSv).

Comment: that's interesting; i always thought that since an overload is a different function with different parameters, then it would be treated as a different function entirely and not interfere with another overload